# "Could not save the list to the server" across all site collections

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I cannot create a custom form on any list on any site collection. I get the infamous "Could not save the list to the server". I am using SharePoint Online on Office 365.

I also noticed that with existing lists, I am unable to add/remove columns from the datasource and it appears to be greyed out.

Any advice? I'd greatly appreciate it.

I did my research on the web and followed instructions. I cleared my we bsite cache. I logged into another computer. I used another account. I checked another site collection. I deleted my columns that I added from the morning. Heck, I even deleted the list I was working with. I have tried everything that I could think of or find.

I have none.

My custom form that I tried to save does not save.

Comment: Perhaps this might be of interest https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/205243/could-not-save-the-list-changes-to-the-server-in-designer

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has an advisory on the Microsoft 365 Admin Center.

SP186130 Can't Create Forms. Scope:  Any user attempting to create new forms on SharePoint Online lists via SharePoint Designer is affected.